# transaction behaviour with subselect

Tags: oracle

I am wondering about the following strange behaviour.

This function should log the selected data to a table `ps_cs_corr_data_tb` (this table is empty):

```
create or replace function cs_corr_data(i_id in varchar2,
                                        i_key1 in varchar2,
                                        i_key2 in varchar2,
                                        i_key3 in varchar2,
                                        i_key4 in varchar2,
                                        i_key5 in varchar2)
  return number as pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin

  insert into ps_cs_corr_data_tb
    (descr,
     cs_key_id_01,
     cs_key_id_02,
     cs_key_id_03,
     cs_key_id_04,
     cs_key_id_05)
  values
    (i_id, i_key1, i_key2, i_key3, i_key4, i_key5);
  commit;
  return 1; /* insert successful */
exception
  when dup_val_on_index then
    return 0;
end;
```

**Test a)**

The test with the following select statement is successful (as expected):

```
select b.id, b.key1, b.key2, b.key3, b.key4, b.key5
  from (select a.id, a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, a.key4, a.key5
          from ( -- test data 
                select '1' as id,'1' as key1,' ' as key2,' ' as key3,' ' as key4,' ' as key5 from dual union all
                select '1' as id,'2' as key1,' ' as key2,' ' as key3,' ' as key4,' ' as key5 from dual union all
                select '1' as id,'3' as key1,' ' as key2,' ' as key3,' ' as key4,' ' as key5 from dual union all
                select '1' as id,'4' as key1,' ' as key2,' ' as key3,' ' as key4,' ' as key5 from dual union all
                select '1' as id,'5' as key1,' ' as key2,' ' as key3,' ' as key4,' ' as key5 from dual 
               ) a
        -- some conditions        
         where a.id = '1'
           and a.key1 = '4') b
-- log the results of selection           
 where cs_corr_data(b.id, b.key1, b.key2, b.key3, b.key4, b.key5) = 1;
```

result of selection:

```
ID  KEY1    KEY2    KEY3    KEY4    KEY5
1   4
```

result in logging table:

```
select * from ps_cs_corr_data_tb d;

 DESCR  CS_KEY_ID_01    CS_KEY_ID_02    CS_KEY_ID_03    CS_KEY_ID_04    CS_KEY_ID_05
 1      4
```

So far the expected result!

Explain Plan:

```
Plan hash value: 334628103

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     5 |    90 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  VIEW            |      |     5 |    90 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL      |      |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    FILTER        |      |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     FAST DUAL    |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    FILTER        |      |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |     FAST DUAL    |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |    FILTER        |      |       |       |            |          |
|   8 |     FAST DUAL    |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |    FILTER        |      |       |       |            |          |
|  10 |     FAST DUAL    |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |    FILTER        |      |       |       |            |          |
|  12 |     FAST DUAL    |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL AND "CS_CORR_DATA"('1','1',' ',' ',' ',' 
              ')=1)
   5 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL AND "CS_CORR_DATA"('1','2',' ',' ',' ',' 
              ')=1)
   7 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL AND "CS_CORR_DATA"('1','3',' ',' ',' ',' 
              ')=1)
   9 - filter("CS_CORR_DATA"('1','4',' ',' ',' ',' ')=1)
  11 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL AND "CS_CORR_DATA"('1','5',' ',' ',' ',' 
              ')=1)
```

**Test b)**

Now *the same test* with different test data preparation (but the same test data):

```
select b.id, b.key1, b.key2, b.key3, b.key4, b.key5
  from (select a.id, a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, a.key4, a.key5
          from (select '1' as id,
                       to_char(level) as key1,
                       ' ' as key2,
                       ' ' as key3,
                       ' ' as key4,
                       ' ' as key5
                  from dual
                connect by level <= 5) a
         where a.id = '1'
           and a.key1 = '4') b
 where cs_corr_data(b.id, b.key1, b.key2, b.key3, b.key4, b.key5) = 1;
```

result of selection:

```
ID  KEY1    KEY2    KEY3    KEY4    KEY5
1   4
```

result in logging table:

```
select * from ps_cs_corr_data_tb d;

 DESCR  CS_KEY_ID_01    CS_KEY_ID_02    CS_KEY_ID_03    CS_KEY_ID_04    CS_KEY_ID_05
 1      1                
 1      2                
 1      3                
 1      4                
 1      5
```

Explain Plan:

```
Plan hash value: 2403765415

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |      |     1 |    37 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                         |      |     1 |    37 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    FAST DUAL                  |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("CS_CORR_DATA"("A"."ID","A"."KEY1","A"."KEY2","A"."KEY3","A"."KE
              Y4","A"."KEY5")=1 AND "A"."ID"='1' AND "A"."KEY1"='4')
   2 - filter(LEVEL<=5)
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Seems like the second query has the outer predicate pushed down into the a subquery. Please produce the execution plans for both queries and update your question to include them.

Comment: @Boneist execution plans added. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle (along with just about any relational database) is free to evaluate predicates in whatever order it expects would be most efficient.  In either query, it is free to evaluate the function predicate first or to evaluate the `a.id = '1' and a.key1 = '4'` predicates first or to evaluate the function predicate between those two predicates.  It appears that the actual plan the optimizer chose in the second case (at least this time) was to evaluate the function first while it chose to evaluate the function last in the first case.  Of course, the optimizer is free to change its mind tomorrow in both cases so you shouldn't depend on a particular query plan.

Comment: Thank you, i.e. Oracle arbitrary rearranges the conditions of the inner and outer select statements (see execution plans). I didn't consider this.